# grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `aufs'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Sorry about the long post.

I've used Ubuntu once as dual boot with windows 10 long time ago. And yesterday I installed it again. As I had an experience of setting it up on dual boot I was confident enough to do it on my on with the help of some tutorials on internet.

Last time also I got many entries (10+) on Grub boot loader and I've searched through internet and removed them(I thought they are not useful) using Grub-customizer. And at that time it didn't go wrong and I was able to log into Ubuntu or Windows with fewer options in grub menu.
So today also I removed the entries which I thought is not important. And now I can't log into the PC as it shows there's no bootable devices detected.

So now I logged on from Ubuntu live cd and was following https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ this tutorial but couldn't get pass this last step as I'm getting this error
**"Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `a "** .

What have I done wrong ? Is there anyway to fix this ? I mean any way how to get the bootable options (Grub) back ?

edit : This is the way I did it last time
[Remove useless entries from messed up grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823514/remove-useless-entries-from-messed-up-grub)

Comment: #OuchFS. As much pain as the tedious installation process where one typo can wreck the story.

Answer (score 1):

`aufs` belongs to the live system. You should install grub into the installed system, and you can use `chroot` to do that according to the following link to the Ubuntu 'help wiki',

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot)

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a tool that you might find easier to use, but I think it is worth learning the `chroot` method.

- **Edit** after the dialogue of comments:

  The partitioning details are described in the following links,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Partitions)

Comment: I tried the steps and tried to run gparted and getting the error on it too

Comment: Please try **Boot Repair** according to the link in my answer: 1. Post the link to the *Boot Info summary* (output of the Boot-Info script; 2. Try the *Recommended repair*; 3. Please describe with your own words what happens when you reboot after running the *Recommended repair* - Good luck :-)

Comment: @Sudodus...I followed the steps and tried..This is the error I'm getting when I run the Recommended repair in Boot Repair.
_""GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again."_

Comment: This happens when you make a system, that boots in BIOS mode from a drive with a GUID partition table (GPT). The partitioning details are described in the following link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: By the way, do you want to boot in BIOS mode? Or did it just happen?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get u. I need to get grub or windows boot loader as I'm not getting any one of those as the bootable device :(

Comment: Your previous grub entries showed you have UEFI. So you have to always boot in UEFI boot mode not BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot mode.  Then repairs should work. The bios_grub is only for BIOS Boot. UEFI should show two options to boot flash drive UEFI:flash and just flash (which is the BIOS boot) where flash is name or label on flash drive.

Comment: I think @oldfred is right. Please try to boot the *Boot Repair system* in UEFI mode as well as the installed system in UEFI mode. It might work better. (Maybe it 'just happened' that you started to boot in BIOS mode.)

Comment: Can u please tell me how to choose boot mode (UEFI or BIOS) .sorry , I'm a newbie :(

Comment: You choose boot mode very early in the boot process, before the operating starts. It is different between computers. Usually there is a hotkey, for example F12 (but it can be many different keys), and usually it is written to the screen (maybe during one second), so look at the startup screen, maybe more than once to see it. Sometimes it is not written to the screen, but should be possible to find via the internet After hitting the hotkey, there are menus (also different), you must browse *your* particular menu system until you find where to change between BIOS (alias CSM, legacy) and UEFI.

Comment: I checked. I've disabled legacy mode and I'm on UEFI mode

Comment: Good luck :-) and we are here if you need more help ...

Comment: I was on UEFI mode before also. So the problem still persists. And when I turned in gParted it searchs for dev/sda and shows this error "Input/Output error during read on /dev/sda

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59942/discussion-between-sudodus-and-thidasa-paranavitharana).