# “Unusable” entries in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After installing several of my unused OSes using OS-Uninstaller on the Boot Repair disk, the main side effect was tons of useless entries which appear to be directing to my old OSes in GRUB, such as:

- EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi (and mmx64.efi)
- efi/Debian/fbx64.efi (and mmx64.efi) (Obviously points towards Debian)
- EFI/fedora/mmx64.efi (and gcdia32.efi, gcdx64.efi)

I tried updating GRUB, deleting the unused EFI files (then updating GRUB), and even reinstalling GRUB (of course updating GRUB afterwards).

Before I attempted deleting the unused EFI files, the interesting thing is that no matter if it was Fedora, Debian, etc (apart from the Windows entries, as you should be able to see below, which just took me to a GRUB command line), they all booted into Ubuntu.

Edit: The Grub Customizer method doesn’t actually fix the issue, it only covers up the broken entries.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove useless entries from messed up grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823514/remove-useless-entries-from-messed-up-grub)

Comment: No, that answer just hides the entries, not actually fixing the problem with GRUB.

Comment: Okay then try this please https://askubuntu.com/questions/348763/removing-entries-from-uefi-menu-with-efibootmgr

Comment: Those may be grub menu entries created by Boot-Repair and in 25_custom. You can remove, turn off or edit 25_custom at will as not part of standard grub. I turn off os-prober and only add entries I want into 40_custom. https://askubuntu.com/questions/778663/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-uefi-bootmgfw-efi-and-windows-uefi-bkpboo/778705#778705 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700Also do not user grub customizer unless you want simple changes as it adds its own grub files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@oldfred has it correct. The `/etc/grub.d/25_custom` file is what's adding all of the extra unwanted GRUB entries. Placed there by `boot-repair`. `GRUB Customizer` may add similar unnecessary files into `/etc/grub.d`. However, I would not recommend modifying os-prober and/or 40_custom.

These are the standard files that you should see in `/etc/grub.d`...

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  11K Feb  5  2019 00_header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 6.2K Apr 22  2016 05_debian_theme*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  17K Oct 11 06:57 10_linux*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  37K Oct 11 06:57 10_linux_zfs*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  13K Oct 11 06:57 20_linux_xen*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2.0K Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  12K Apr 14  2017 30_os-prober*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.4K Oct 14  2015 30_uefi-firmware*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  214 Sep 22  2014 40_custom*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  216 Apr 11  2014 41_custom*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  483 Apr 11  2014 README
```

`cat /etc/grub.d/25_custom` # confirm that it contains the unwanted entries.

`sudo rm -i /etc/grub.d/25_custom` # to remove this file

`sudo update-grub` # generate new GRUB menu

`reboot` # confirm desired result

Comment: Yep! He was exactly right. Thanks for explaining how to remove them.